# Any good resources to learn templating in play framework 2.0, for Java Developers

Tags: playframework, playframework-2.0

I come from a Java background. It's my first time with the Play Framework and also any Web framework. I decided to kick off with 2.0.
I'm having troubles with the templating in Play 2.0

Any suggestions for better resources than the official Documentation.

Answer (score 3):

As a Player you should also add the following bookmarks: (btw, Scala templates aren't that hard when you take a week to dive in)

**Play! books:**
If you have no experience with Play, you could consider buying this book: http://manning.com/leroux/. Great insight information from a Java Persepctive!!

**Play Wiki:**
Great source is the github wiki as Codemwnci mentioned: https://github.com/playframework/Play20/wiki/JavaTemplates

**Play website**
On the Play! website you often get community updates, news and new tutorials: http://www.playframework.org/community

The following guys often write about Play!:

1. http://www.objectify.be/wordpress/
2. http://www.soutier.de/blog/
3. http://www.joergviola.de/

And Codemwnci's site you also should bookmark :-)

Answer (score 1):

Well the template engine in Play 2.0 is based on Razor from ASP.NET. It is not identical, but if you are unhappy with the official Play documentation, then your next best place to start, would be to look at the documentation online for Razor. The Play documentation is still currently the best place to learn about the templating engine.

For cutting edge version, use github instead of the Play website - https://github.com/playframework/Play20/wiki/JavaTemplates

Also, if you don't like the Play scala templates, you can always use the old groovy template engine. Check out https://github.com/mbknor/gt-engine-play2 for the source and documentation.

Answer (score 0):

Well typesafe provides a good training stuff . You can [check here](https://typesafe.com/how/training). Go to online training. This is best resource to learn play in java as per my information. Thanks to Nilanjan and typesafe for providing such a good training. Also type safe has their youtube channel just check that too. Subscribe to typesafe's news latter if there are any webinars you will be get notified. Use mailing list too.